# add boxes / containers in mermaid sequence diagram

Tags: markdown, sequence-diagram, mermaid

I'm making sequence diagrams with Mermaid, and I find the `loop` feature very cool, drawing a labeled rectangle around a loop with this code chunk:

```
sequenceDiagram
    loop Title
        Alice->>Bob: Hello John, how are you?
        Bob->>Alice: Answer
            loop Title
                Bob->>Bob: Thinks
            end
    end
```

Rendering like this: 
[image]

My question is: Can I use this rectangle container element for something else than a loop, for just grouping things, and naming it whatever i want, other than "loop" (it doesn't work if I change the keyword `loop`). It seems that there are only 'loop', 'opt' and 'alt' authorized keywords?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like `subgraph` is what you want:

```
flowchart TB
    c1-->a2
    subgraph ide1 [one]
    a1-->a2
    end
```

[image: Image from Mermaid documentation]

https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid/#/flowchart?id=subgraphs

Comment: This is for `flowchart` not `sequenceDiagram`. Why was it accepted? 

Comment: Dunno, I guess it applies to both?

Comment: No, it only applies to flowchart.

Comment: came here looking for something specific to `sequence diagrams` more like what [should be the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75900818/3015484) by @Zubin
with `rect + note`

Answer (score 5):

Hi maybe not exact the same you wish but you can try

```
sequenceDiagram
    participant Alice
    participant John
    
    rect rgb(191, 223, 255)
   
        Alice->>Bob: Hello John, how are you?
        Bob->>Alice: Answer
            rect rgb(200, 150, 255)
                Bob->>Bob: Thinks
            end
    end
```

this will create an rectangle

Answer (score 5):

I think `rect` would work for what you're doing: https://mermaid.js.org/syntax/sequenceDiagram.html#background-highlighting has a pretty good example with the following code:

```
sequenceDiagram
    participant Alice
    participant John

    rect rgb(191, 223, 255)
    note right of Alice: Alice calls John.
    Alice->>+John: Hello John, how are you?
    rect rgb(200, 150, 255)
    Alice->>+John: John, can you hear me?
    John-->>-Alice: Hi Alice, I can hear you!
    end
    John-->>-Alice: I feel great!
    end
    Alice ->>+ John: Did you want to go to the game tonight?
    John -->>- Alice: Yeah! See you there.
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`alt` or `opt` can help you achieve this:

```
sequenceDiagram
    Alice->>Bob: Hello Bob, how are you?
    alt is sick
        Bob->>Alice: Not so good :(
    else is well
        Bob->>Alice: Feeling fresh like a daisy
    end
    opt Extra response
        Bob->>Alice: Thanks for asking
    end
```

See [documentation](https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid/#/sequenceDiagram?id=alt)

Answer (score 2):

To label a section which isn't a `loop`, `alt` (alternative path), or `opt` (optional); use [Critical Region](https://mermaid.js.org/syntax/sequenceDiagram.html#critical-region):

[image]